# How to get flag count for any time period

Tags: 7, views, flags

I have View which displays a list of nodes with counters (flags), but the counters for all the time. How to display a list of nodes with counters (flags), for example, over the last week or last month?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the filter criteria : Flagged Time and eventually expose it to users?[image]

Then you can define : 
- the operator: is equal to / is less than / ...
- a specific date or offset

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tried it. I get the nodes which are marked in a given period of time, but the counter flags these nodes for all time.